# the output when I start firefox from Terminal

Tags: command-line, firefox

I was curious and wanted to see if I could start Firefox using Terminal. So I typed

```
firefox
```

in Terminal, and it displayed the message below

```
(process:5199): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
```

And Firefox started running. But I am a little worried because the message above looks like an error message to me. Can anyone tell me what it means?

Comment: Such messages accompany almost *every* GUI app when I run them from the terminal.

Comment: This is a known bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=833117

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It always happens with me too.  They say it is a bug but to my experience, it doesn't  affect performance at all.
So you may ignore the message and continue using Firefox