# Whenever I open firefox from terminal there is an error

Tags: firefox, glib

Currently using 14.04 and whenever I open firefox from terminal this error message comes (of course it does open firefox and it works fine)

```
(process:7949): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
```

What does it mean and how to rectify it?

Comment: Just ignore them. Practically any GUI app you run from a terminal will spew such messages.

Comment: Thanks Eric Carvalho. Didn't know it was already answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out it's already been answered here. Just ignore it, it seems. I would be happy to ignore them.

[the output when I start firefox from Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519465/the-output-when-i-start-firefox-from-terminal)

Comment: Hi GSP, if you agree it is a duplicate, probably better to remove the question (click "delete" below the question) than creating an additional answer. This creates an extra set of Q/A which does not add anything to the site .